# Laravel safest way to delete a many to many relationship data while sync (replace) with another

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many, eloquent-relationship

I have a project with Product, Category relationship which is Many to Many

```
// Product Model
public function categories()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}

//Category Model
public function products()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Now, when a some category gets deleted, I want to assign it's products to a default category (ID = 1).
What is the best way to achieve this with Laravel 8

Comment: You have access to `attach()`, `detach()`, `sync()` and `syncWithoutDetaching()` methods, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations. Have you tried anything? I think you should be able to **detach** existing **Products** from the **Category** you're deleting, and **attach** them to your default **Category**.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I finally managed to make it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try the [deleting event](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures):

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public static function booted()
    {
        static::deleting(function ($category) {
            $products = $category->products()->get();

            if ($products->isNotEmpty()) {
                $category->products()->detach();
                $defaultCategory = static::find(1);
                $defaultCategory->products()->sync($products->pluck('id')->toArray());
            }
            
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin, your answer got me into path. With little modification it is working now! I will add my final version below for anyone who wants to know.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution thanks to Kevin

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function ($category) {
        $products = $category->products;

        if ($products->isNotEmpty()) {
            $category->products()->detach();
            $defaultCategory = static::find(1);
            $defaultCategory->products()->sync($products->pluck('id')->toArray());
        }
        
    });
}
```

Comment: Pls make this the correct answer if it solves your problem.